# How to implement a round-robin queue consumer in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rabbit

I am building a message driven service in spring which will run in a cluster and needs to pull messages from a RabbitMQ queue in a round robin manner. The implementation is currently pulling messages off the queue in a first come basis leading to some servers getting backed up while others are idle.

The current QueueConsumerConfiguration.java looks like :

```
@Configuration
public class QueueConsumerConfiguration extends RabbitMqConfiguration {
private Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QueueConsumerConfiguration.class);

private static final int DEFAULT_CONSUMERS=2;

@Value("${eventservice.inbound}")
protected String inboudEventQueue;

@Value("${eventservice.consumers}")
protected int queueConsumers;

@Autowired
private EventHandler eventtHandler;

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
    template.setRoutingKey(this.inboudEventQueue);
    template.setQueue(this.inboudEventQueue);
    template.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    return template;
}

@Bean
public Queue inboudEventQueue() {
    return new Queue(this.inboudEventQueue);
}

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer() {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    container.setQueueNames(this.inboudEventQueue);
    container.setMessageListener(messageListenerAdapter());
    if (this.queueConsumers > 0) {
        LOG.info("Starting queue consumers:" + this.queueConsumers );
        container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(this.queueConsumers);
        container.setConcurrentConsumers(this.queueConsumers);
    } else {
        LOG.info("Starting default queue consumers:" + DEFAULT_CONSUMERS);
        container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(DEFAULT_CONSUMERS);
        container.setConcurrentConsumers(DEFAULT_CONSUMERS);            
    }
    return container;
}

@Bean
public MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter() {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(this.eventtHandler, jsonMessageConverter());
}
}
```

Is it a case of just adding

```
container.setChannelTransacted(true);
```

to the configuration?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean - the default prefetch (1) means each consumer will be sent one message at a time (round robin). RabbitMQ doesn't know the difference  between 3 consumers in one container Vs. 3 containers with 1 consumer each - they are all consumers from Rabbit's perspective.

Comment: I think that is my problem. What I am looking for is a way to configure so that the 3 consumers are not being treated sequentially when they are registered with RabbitMQ. If I have 3 containers (1,2,3) and two consumers on each (A,B) when those containers start I am seeing them as A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3 - where I would rather them be more randomly distributed. Is it possible to leave the container.setConcurrentConsumers and have those consumers start as needed? I thought I read of a conflict with CachingConnectionFactory which I think is needed to be able to pass in authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ treats all consumers the same - it knows no difference between multiple consumers in one container Vs. one consumer in multiple containers (e.g. on different hosts). Each is a consumer from Rabbit's perspective.

If you want more control over server affinity, you need to use multiple queues with each container listening to its own queue.

You then control the distribution on the producer side - e.g. using a topic or direct exchange and specific routing keys to route messages to a specific queue.

This tightly binds the producer to the consumers (he has to know how many there are).

Or you could have your producer use routing keys `rk.0, rk.1, ..., rk.29` (repeatedly, resetting to 0 when 30 is reached).

Then you can bind the consumer queues with multiple bindings -

consumer 1 gets rk.0 to rk.9, 2 gets rk.10 to rk.19, etc, etc.

If you then decide to increase the number of consumers, just refactor the bindings appropriately to redistribute the work.

The container will scale up to maxConcurrentConsumers on demand but, practically, scaling down only occurs when the entire container is idle for some time.