# Spring Boot RabbitMQ - How to make sure multiple consumers consume messages one at a time

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm using Spring Boot + RabbitMQ server and for one of my Queues I want my multiple consumers to consume the messages serially i.e.

`Expexted Behaviour
consumer1: message1 xxxxxxxx message3 xxxxxxxx
consumer2: xxxxxxxx message2 xxxxxxxx message4`

Right now I'm using the following to achieve exclusivity:

`@RabbitListener(queues = Constants.QUEUE_TOPIC, exclusive = true)`

But this only allows one active consumer at a time, so my functionality is not breaking but scalability is.

Please suggest the correct way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a round-robin queue consumer in Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505871/how-to-implement-a-round-robin-queue-consumer-in-spring-boot)

Comment: thanks for the link! but honestly that question and the accepted answer is not making much sense to me :/ plus it's been a long time and I'm hoping for a better solution if any!

Answer (score 0):

Follow these step , it might help you out :(pseudocode)

**Sender.java :-**

Class Sender {

1. static final String QUEUE_NAME = "queue_name";

void main(String[] argv){

2. Establish connection.
3. Declare queue.

   =>channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
4. Publish multiple messages in same queue:

   =>int count; //user input for no of messages by scanner

   =>publish ["message"+i] with i++ in channel.basicPublish() in while loop for count   times
5. Close channel connection.

}

}

**MessageConsumer.java:-**

class MessageConsumer{

1. static final String QUEUE_NAME = "queue_name";

void main(String[] argv){

2. Establish connection.
3. Declare queue.

   =>channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
4. Use channel.basicQos(1);  //consumer prefetch.
5. Consume messages using  final Consumer consumer = new Defaultconsumer()
   {public void handleDelivery{...}};
6. channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, consumer);)

}

}

Run 2 or more instances of MessagerConsumer.java for checking serial consumption of messages

Then run the Sender.java with according user inputs.

See if u get the desired results with this.

Comment: Can you motivate your solution?

Comment: multiple consumer will get messages those are queued in the queue one at a time with the help of ==>channel.basicQos(1); //consumer prefetch. ...... jusd run the multiple instances of MessageConsumer.java in thorugh command line or in console and you will get the expected behaviour

Comment: Thanks @K-DEV let me try this and share my findings.

Comment: @KaranGujral ... Tried?